# Entity relationships in POSTed JSON with Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Spring Boot (using Jackson) handles object mapping quite well between a JSON document and a Java POJO. For example:

```
{ id: 5, name: "Christopher" }
```

can be accepted by:

```
@PostMapping("/students/{id}")
public Student Update(Long studentId, @RequestBody Student student) {

    studentRepository.save(student);

    return student;
}
```

and will be correctly mapped into:

```
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

But what about nested models in the JSON?

```
{ id: 5, name: "Christopher", grades: [ {id: 1, letter: 'A'} ] }
```

Or optional models in the JSON?

```
{ id: 5, name: "Christopher" }
(Purposefully leaving out 'grades', though it could be accepted.)
```

Or indicating the removal of an association in JSON (example using Rails' _destroy flag)?

```
{ id: 5, name: "Christopher", grades: [ {id: 1, letter: 'A', _destroy: true} ] }
```

Or creating an association by leaving out the ID?

```
{ id: 5, name: "Christopher", grades: [ {letter: 'A-'} ] }
```

Does Spring Boot support these ideas?

Comment: If you mean by 'optional models' somethink like Optional<String> whatever; you shouldnt use Optionals in Pojos.

Comment: Not necessarily optional models, just optional whether or not that should be in the JSON. If 'Student' has a list of 'Grades' but I only want to update a student's name, I don't want to have to POST their 'Grades' array each time.

Comment: I've used Data Transfer Object (DTOs) to solve the Problem you describe. You can also add @JsonIgnore annotation on Fields which you don't want to serialized.

Answer (score 1):

> But what about nested models in the JSON?

Nested Models are mapped as you maybe would expect, assume you have the following model:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private List<Price> prices;
}


public class ProductPrice {
     Long idPrice;
     Integer amountInCents;
}
```

Jackson would create the following JSON from this Schema:

```
{
    "name":"Samsung Galaxy S7",
    "prices":[
         {
              "idPrice":0,
              "amountInCents": 100
         }
    ]
}
```

> Or optional models in the JSON?

You can annote field with @JsonIgnore. If you, for example, annotate the prices with @JsonIgnore, no prices will be serialized from jackson.

> Or indicating the removal of an association in JSON (example using
>   Rails' _destroy flag)?

I would create an additional mapping to delete a associations. This has another advantage, the API is self explaining..

```
 @DeleteMapping("/students/{id}/grade/{idGrade}")
 public Student Update(Long studentId, @PathVariable Long idGrade) {

     studentService.deleteGrade(studentId,idGrade);

     return student;
}
```

> Or creating an association by leaving out the ID?

I would here also create an additional Mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/students/{id}/grade")
public Student Update(Long studentId, @PathVariable String grade) {

     studentService.addGrade(studentId,grade);

     return student;
}
```

Note: I do not use repositories directly, I create a service layer and every repository has package protected access. In the service layer you create methods like addGrade, deleteGrad, addStudent, deleteStudent and so on

Comment: Thank you, this is a pretty complete answer. But what if I want to serialize a nested model only if I happened to include the data? @JsonIgnore acts as though the association doesn't exist at all. But I may want to create an object with its nested object at the same time, or I may wish to leave it out. Is this behavior supported?

Comment: I've never tried it, but take a look at Jackson JSON Views. I think this should fit your targets. Here is a nice blog post: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation